# how to ORDER BY on a field with alias

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have query as follows

```
   SELECT
  final_avg_total.`Provider Name`,
  ROUND(SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments), 2) AS avg_payments,
  ROUND(SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges), 2) AS avg_covered,
  (SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) - SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments)) / SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS total_average,
  1 - (SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) - SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments))/SUM(final_avg_total.avg_covered_charges) AS total_percentage
FROM final_avg_total
GROUP BY final_avg_total.`Provider Id`
ORDER BY final_avg_total.`avg_payments`  DESC
```

i want to do order by on the following field with alias `avg_payments`, but i am getting this error.

```
 Unknown column avg_payments in the order by clause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`avg_payments` is not a field in the table.  Just remove the table alias:

```
ORDER BY avg_payments  DESC
```

MySQL understands column aliases in `order by` statements.

Comment: i want to apply order  by on `ROUND(SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments), 2) AS avg_payments` , if i do as you say i am not getting required answer

Comment: What is the issue that you are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

avg_payments is not an attribute of final_avg_total, maybe just do :

```
ORDER BY avg_payments  DESC
```

Comment: i want to apply order by on `ROUND(SUM(final_avg_total.avg_total_payments), 2) AS avg_payments` , if i do as you say i am not getting required answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
order by 2.
```

1 Represents the ordinal position in your select statement which is final_avg_total.`Provider Name` then 2 will means it is avg_payments.

Note: This only works in mysql if Im not mistaken.

Hopes this helps.